# Excel formula using initial criteria then searching within cell for specific text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to write an Excel formula to first use a criteria to determine which row to search in, and then look within a certain cell in that row for specific (possibly partial) text. [image]

For example, I would use the account number in B3 (100001) as the first criteria, then want it to search within F2:G5 to see if there is a row that contains that account number and the associated ticker from C3 (SNL). I I don't need it to stop after just seeing the first instance of that account number not having the ticker, because it does exist 2 rows down.

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C3,G3:G5))),INDEX(F3:F5,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B3,G3:G5)),0)))
```

I know this is a bit off, but feel like this sort of idea might be on the right track. Really just need to return "True" if the account number is found in the second set with that ticker, and "False" if not.

Thank you very much to anyone who may be able to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `COUNTIFS` with wildcards:

```
=COUNTIFS(F$3:F$5,B3,G$3:G$5,"*"&C3&"*")>0
```

[image]